# 'v-bind' directives require an attribute value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create some type of tree with vue.js and stuck on a problem with element props. Help me out plz.

I've tried `:content="{{tempCont}}"` and I've tried `content="{{tempCont}}"`, but none of them worked.

Here's the place where I am using `tree` element:

```
<div id="tree">
    <treeItem :title="Parent" :content="{{tempCont}}"></treeItem>
</div>
```

Here's the entire tree element:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p v-on:click="openTree">{{title}}</p>
        <div id="childs" v-if="childVisibility">
            <treeItem v-for="item in content" :key="item" title=item>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: {
        childVisibility: false
    },

    methods: {
        openTree: function(){
            childVisibility = !childVisibility;
        }
    },

    props: {
        title: String,
        content: Array,
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I am getting this error:[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok so first of all, when you v-bind something like `v-bind:title` or `:title`, what you bind is expressed as a javascript expression.

So if you want your `title` attribute to be the string `Parent`, you need either to write it like a native html attribute `title="Parent"` (notice the lack of `:`), or as a vue bound attribute `v-bind:title="'Parent'"` or `:title="'Parent'"` (notice the use of `''` to express a string primitive type in javascript.

Now, the `{{ variable }}` syntax is used inside vuejs template but you do not need to use it inside v-bind attributes since they are already interpreted as javascript.

So you shouldn't write this:

```
<div id="tree">
    <treeItem :title="Parent" :content="{{tempCont}}"></treeItem>
</div>
```

but this instead:

```
<div id="tree">
    <treeItem title="Parent" :content="tempCont"></treeItem>
</div>
```

Since`tempCont` is already a valid javascript expression.

Answer (score 23):

Use like this: `:content="tempCont"`

```html
<div id="tree">
  <treeItem :title="Parent" :content="tempCont"></treeItem>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh gosh, that was too easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need `{{}}` for passing attributes.

```
<treeItem :title="Parent" :content="tempCont"></treeItem>
```

This shall be good enough to work. The puspose of `{{}}` is to print data and not pass attributes.
Also, in your tree component, it's a good practice to follow object notations in your props. For ex:

```
props: {
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    content: {
        type: Array
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why should I use objects? Is this just a good style of code? Or it can impact sth?

Comment: It is good style code and also you can set other parameters for your props like running some validation or setting up defaults. As per the official documentation, it is fine to use this style of declaring props but in general it is good if you follow object declaration format.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also you should make your components data reactive and making sure that childVisibility is set to this instance rather than a direct reference by setting it like this

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        childVisibility: false
    }
},

methods: {
    openTree() {
        this.childVisibility = !this.childVisibility;
    }
},

props: {
    title: String,
    content: Array,
}
```

}